# Action Bar com menu de tabs fixo

Tags: android

Estou com uma dúvida em criar um menu de navegação fixo como esse

[image]

Como fazer para conseguir deixar o PagerTabStrip fixo como da imagem?

O código que tenho para utilização é esse

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Você pode colocar os botões no topo e `fragments` que serão alternados na parte de baixo. Pesquisar sobre `fragments` é interessante.

Comment: Estou querendo saber como deixar o PagerTabStrip fixo como da imagem

Answer (score 1):

Se utilizando o `PagerTitleStrip` e o `PagerTabStrip` não atendem pois eles se movimentam conforme ocorre a navegação.

Sugiro então a utilização da biblioteca [`ViewPagerIndicator`](http://viewpagerindicator.com/), feita pelo Jake Wharton, que mantém o mesmo comportamento (igual a imagem) porém com mais customizações.

Existe também outra library que faz a mesma coisa, porém possui um efeito de sliding no indicador de aba. Seria no caso a [`PagerSlidingTabStrip`](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip), feita pelo Andreas Stütz, porém a essência é a mesma.

Utilizando a `ViewPagerIndicator` seria algo como:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fora do `ViewPager`, diferente do `PagerTabStrip`.

E para configurar o `ViewPager` com o `TitlePageIndicator` seria algo como:

```
//Set the pager with an adapter
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

//Bind the title indicator to the adapter
TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.titles);
titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

Assim como está na documentação que pode ser vista pelo site [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) ou pelo [github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator).